# How to write code to NOT include null value fields into mongodb

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

```
class State
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :cities
  field :name
end

class City
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :state
  field :name
  field :population
  field ...
end
```

I don't want to include the fields with nil value into mongodb,

```
nsw = State.new name: 'NSW'
if number_of_people
  nsw.cities.create name: 'Syndey', population: number_of_people
else
  nsw.cities.create name: 'Syndey'
end
```

so it is necessary to check whether or not that field is empty or null. But the problem is when there are many fields in City, the code looks ugly.

How to improve this and write smart code?

Comment: I don't understand one thing.. this code `nsw.cities.create name: 'Syndey'` will set nil to population as well !! what's the default value if you don't want it nil ??

Comment: Nope, it will not create a population field.

Comment: I got it. check out my answer below.

Comment: @Zakwan did you. I think it's simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a custom class method in `City` model like the following:

```
def self.create_persistences(fields = {})
  attributes = {}
  fields.each do |key, value|
    attributes[key] = value if value
  end

  create attributes
end
```

and in your controller, call this method without conditions hassle:

`nsw.cities.create_persistences name: 'Syndey', population: number_of_people`

note: you can also override `create` method on your model instead of defining new method but in my opinion, I don't prefer to override something you may use in other part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Now we know what you are doing your answer seems clear. But I think your question needs an edit to inform.

So what you have is data from some source that you are using to populate your new model. So at some stage here you **are** going to have a *hash* or at least some way of constructing a *hash* in some form from however your data is organized. Take the following [short form but the same thing]:

```
info = { name: "Sydney", population: 100 }

City.new( info );

info = { name: "Melbourne", population: 80, info: "fun" }

City.new( info )

info = { name: "Adelaide" }

City.new( info )
```

So (at least in my testing ), you are going to get each document, with only the specified fields created each time.

So dynamically using the hash (and hopefully you are even just reading in that way ) is going to be a lot smarter than testing each value in code.

If you have to do a lot of value testing to even "build up" a *hash* then you have problems that no-one here can fix. But building hashes should be easy.